# Printing back javascript code to user

Tags: javascript

I want to print or echo back code to the user, but when I attempt to I get an ILLEGAL error. How would I go about showing the below code as just normal text instead of executing it:

`alert('<script>hello</script>');`

I've been trying to print it to a text box with jQuery when I get the error, like so:

`$('.printed-code').val('<script> write your code between these lines </script>');`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WgxrW/1

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need this? It seems an akward thing to want to do. If it is for debugging, there are better ways :) I do not understand why it is really necessary to show the script tags (they are causing the problem). If it is a code block you want to show, use `pre` tags, and show code.

Comment: I'm writing a WordPress plugin where users can select select options and input things and then generate a set of code that they can then use in themes and templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are placing your JavaScript in a `<script>` element, then the `</script>` in the string literal will be recognised as a matching end tag for the script. Break up the string with an escape sequence (in a JS string literal, `\/` means the same as `/`):

```
$('.printed-code').val('<script> write your code between these lines <\/script>');
```

… or keep the script in an external file and reference it with `<script src="foo.js"></script>`.

---

If you want to display information to a user, then you shouldn't be using an `<input>` to do so, so you will be wanting the `text()` method, not the `val()` method. (Assuming `.printed-code` matches a `<code>` element or something else that is appropriate for the task at hand).

```
$('code.printed-code').text('<script> write your code between these lines </script>');
```

Comment: great answer, exactly what I was looking for!

`$('.printed-code').val('<\script> write your code between these lines <\/script>');`

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the `/` like this: `<\/script>`. Otherwise you get errors, especially in old browsers where `</` ends the script block (not `</script>`)

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered earlier with an exact code example, and included a jsfiddle. He deleted the post for some reason but this was the code he provided. I would have marked that as correct. thank you all for the input

```
$('.printed-code').val('<scr'+'ipt> write your code between these lines </scr'+'ipt>');
```

Comment: Don't do that. Breaking up the start tag is unnecessary and using string concatenation to break up the end tag do this is messy and inefficient.

Comment: Why include the `<script>` tags in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

The `script` tags are being interpreted literally.

Try:

```
alert('&lt;script&gt;hello&lt;/script&gt;')
```

Comment: `alert` doesn't convert HTML entities to text, they are shwon as they are. Not my downvote though.